# How to change root and itemlist name in XML API in a django view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Am trying to change root and list-items name to fit API requirements. I don't want to change XMLRenderer class in renderer.py because i might use it again, I just want to use view to customize.

**The following are the Serializer classes, view class and output**

Serializer class

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TypeCategory
        fields = '__all__'


class ZoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = CategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Type
        fields = ('TypeDesc', 'type')
```

in view

```
class ZoneLists(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, XMLRenderer)

    def get(self, request):
        zone1 = Type.objects.all()

        serializer = ZoneSerializer(zone1, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Output

```
<root>
 <list-item>
  <TypeDesc>NORMAL</TypeDesc>
  <type>
   <list-item>
    <id>5</id>
    <Category>Normal</Category>
    <Type>1</Type>
   </list-item>
  </type>
 </list-item>
 <list-item>
  <TypeDesc>ZONES</TypeDesc>
  <type>
   <list-item>
    <id>9</id>
    <Category>Zone manager</Category>
    <Type>4</Type>
   </list-item>
   <list-item>
    <id>10</id>
    <Category>zone officials</Category>
    <Type>4</Type>
   </list-item>
  </type>
 </list-item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the XMLRenderer in a renderer.py file in your project and overwrite the root_tag_name and item_tag_name like this:

```
from rest_framework_xml.renderers import XMLRenderer


class MyXMLRenderer(XMLRenderer):
    """Custom root renderer which serializes to XML"""
    root_tag_name = "my-custom-root"
    item_tag_name = "my-item-tag"

    def _to_xml(self, xml, data):
        """
        Print list inside dict with tag name = key associated to the list
        e.g. 
            my_list = ['a','b','c']
            my_dict = {'my_element': my_list}
        will be rendered as:
            <my_element>a</my_element>
            <my_element>b</my_element>
            <my_element>c</my_element>
        """
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for key, value in data.items():
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    for item in value:
                        xml.startElement(key, {})
                        self._to_xml(xml, item)
                        xml.endElement(key)
                else:
                    xml.startElement(key, {})
                    self._to_xml(xml, value)
                    xml.endElement(key)
        else:
            super()._to_xml(xml, data)
```

Feel free to add or remove parts of the derived class.